# how I can save an Object with mongoose after collaction created in NestJs

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I have NestJs with mongoose, I want to save an object when mongoose makes my collection. how I can do that?

for example I have a role schema I want when mongoose makes role collection which happens once, it save guest role in the collection.

how I can call my catService here?

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([
      {
        name: 'Cat',
        imports: [ConfigModule],
        useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
          const schema = CatsSchema;
          schema.pre('save', () =>
```

```
      **catService.save({name:'tom'}) //HERE FOREXAMPLE**
```

```
          );
          return schema;
        },
        inject: [ConfigService],
      },
    ]),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}

Plugins#
```

Comment: Please provide more detailed information.

Comment: for example I have a role schema I want when mongoose makes role collection which happens once, it save guest role in the collection.